# javascript hide div on click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have this **HTML Code:**

```
<div class="show_menu" <?php echo $show_menu; ?>><a>Show Menu</a></div>
<div class="hide_menu" <?php echo $hide_menu; ?>><a>Hide Menu</a></div>

<div id="nav">
menu code here...
</div>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if($_SESSION["integradigital.co.uk"]["menu_state"] == 'visable')
{
    $show_menu = 'style="display:none;"';
    $hide_menu = 'style="display:block;"';
    $page_cont = '';
    $nav = 'style="display:block;"';
}
elseif($_SESSION["domain.co.uk"]["menu_state"] == 'hidden')
{
    $show_menu = 'style="display:block;"';
    $hide_menu = 'style="display:none;"';
    $page_cont = 'width:100%;';
    $nav = 'style="display:none;"';
}
elseif($_SESSION["domain.co.uk"]["menu_state"] == '')
{
    $show_menu = 'style="display:none;"';
    $hide_menu = 'style="display:block;"';
    $page_cont = '';
    $nav = 'style="display:block;"';
}
?>
```

and **JS Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript.php">
    $('.show_menu').click(function () {
        $('#nav').toggle();
        $("#page_cont").css("margin-left", "200px");
        $(".hide_menu").css("display", "block");
        $(".show_menu").css("display", "none");
        jQuery('#div_session_write').load('headervertical.php?menu_state=visable');
    });
    $('.hide_menu').click(function () {
        $('#nav').toggle();
        $("#page_cont").css("margin-left", "0");
        $(".hide_menu").css("display", "none");
        $(".show_menu").css("display", "block");
        jQuery('#div_session_write').load('headervertical.php?menu_state=hidden');
    });
</script>
```

so when you click the hide menu link the nav div will hide and set a session variable so when the page is refreshed the menu will stay hidden and the same for when the user clicks on show menu.

its not doing anything when you click hide menu/show menu though and i cant work out why

Comment: Why you don't use cookies? There is a jquery plugin for cookies.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two different buttons for switching on and off menu, use show/hide instead of toggling '#nav'

Where is session_start() ?

Comment: here is some more PHP at the top of the page: <?php
session_start();
if($_GET['menu_state'] > '')
{
 $_SESSION["integradigital.co.uk"]['menu_state'] = $_GET['menu_state'];
}
?>

Comment: Have you tried using chrome inspector or firebug in firefox to debug javascript?

Comment: This answer should be a comment on the question not an answer.

Comment: Yup, sorry about that.